# Merge partition on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, partition, diskutil, macos

I wanted to format and merge 2 partitions on my external hard drive.
I used the command :

```
diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" "" /dev/disks4s4.
```

But now I lost 30go on 2TB and I can't merge the 30go I deleted.

So now it looks like this:

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Maxtor⁩                  299.6 GB   disk4s2
                    (free space)                         134.3 MB   -
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨Donné⁩                   1.7 TB     disk4s3
                    (free space)                         30.9 GB    -
```

How can I merge the 30,9go to "Donné" which is in ExFat without losing data in "Donné"

Comment: What is the format of ⁨Donné⁩? ExFAT, FAT32 or NTFS?

Comment: The format is ExFat @DavidAnderson

Comment: Do you have an Intel Mac or Apple Silicon Mac?

Comment: Apple Silicon Mac M1 @DavidAnderson

Comment: Is `disk0s2` correct in your question?

Comment: Sorry I edit this, I don't use this command line. I only use the first command line

Answer (score 1):

Diskutil can't resize ExFat partitions.

That's only possible on Jhfs+ or Apfs format.

May be possible with Windows tools.

Comment: Alternative app can do that ? Do you know an app ?

Comment: On Mac Os X? I don't know, but before using any third party tool, don't forget to backup all your data. In this case you can start with `diskutil resizevolume disk4s2 0b`

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, finding software which can resize ExFAT is somewhere between difficult to impossible, regardless of the following.

- Linux, macOS, and Windows operating systems.
- Live or installed.
- Paid, trial, or free software

Searching [superuser](https://superuser.com/search?q=resize%20exfat), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=resize%20exfat) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=resize%20exfat) results in links to this type of [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/393132/shrink-exfat-partition). To run [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com) would require Windows, which would require installing [Parallels](https://www.parallels.com). This probably could be done for free on a trial basis.

Instead of Parallels, there also is [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) which can be used for free. However, I am not sure UTM currently supports access to external USB drives from virtual machines.